# Limit of an improper integral with trickery

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Find the limit,

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_x^1\frac{f(t)}{t^3}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Where $\:f:[0,1]\:$ is continuous.

Since $$f\in\mathcal{C}^0([0,1])\implies f\in\mathcal{R}([x,1])\text{ s.t. }\forall \epsilon>0 : \bigcup_{0<x<1}[x,1-\epsilon]\subset[0,1]$$

Also, for  $t\mapsto t^{-3}>0$ on $[x,1]$ and $t^{-3}$ is locally integrable.

Thus, by the first mean value theorem for integrals,

$$I_t=\int_x^1\frac{f(t)}{t^3}\,\text{d}t=f(\gamma)\int_x^1t^{-3}\,\text{d}t,\:\:\gamma\in[x,1]\\\implies I_t=\frac{f(\gamma)}{2}\left({1}/{x^2}-1\right)\\\implies \lim_{x\to0^+}I_t=\infty$$

But the answer should be $\left.f(0)\middle/2\right.$ and the teacher used $x^2\cdot\int_x^1\frac{f(t)}{t^3}\,\text{d}t$ to calculate the limit but like I don't get it I mean this isn't the integral we're looking for. How can we just add $x^2$ and then go about finding the limit?

Comment: Clearly it diverges $f(0) \ne 0$. Your teacher probably meant $\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^3}dt = f(0)\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t^3}dt+\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t^3}dt = \frac{f(0)}{2}x^{-2} + o(x^{-2})$

Answer (score 1):

Using L'Hospital's Rule (LHR) we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^2\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^3}\,dt&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^3}\,dt}{\frac1{x^2}}\right)\\\\
&\overbrace{=}_{LHR}\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{-\frac{f(x)}{x^3}}{-\frac2{x^3}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac12f(0)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Right but what justifies the use of $\:x^2\:$ ? I mean isn't now a different limit since we arbitrarily add a term?

Comment: Obviously, the limit of the integral, without the factor $x^2$ is $\infty$.  In fact, as was already discussed in a comment, $\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^3}\,dt=\frac12 f(0)/x^2+o(1/x^2)$, where $x^2\,o(1/x^2)\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$.  The analysis herein supports this directly.